# Execute script os dependent from java code

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos

I'm developing a java application. I need to call an user script in some point of my app, Since my app can be executed on windows, linux and osx I'd like to start a script in os independent way if possible. Currently I use this on windows for bat file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start user.bat");
```

But on Linux I should do:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", "user.sh" });
```

I can check the OS where the application is running, but I'm wondering if there is an alternative way.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that question. That question is about how to determine the host operating system, and this question asks how to avoid doing that.

Comment: u are right, i misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the command in a config file, and read that file from your program. Make different config files for each operating system. When you distribute your program, include the config file for the target operating system.

Once a program requires things that depend on the host operating system, there are no good solutions.